# How to import first column using =IMPORTHTML?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import this table:

[image]

Source: https://www.tradeskillmaster.com/black-market?realm=EU-draenor

However, upon using `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.tradeskillmaster.com/black-market?realm=EU-draenor","table")`, the first column remains blank.

[image]

Test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MVgD5MUgOik89MMZweLKMZQLSkMeBNoCN_FrPe-eZ5U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, `IMPORTXML` is used instead of `IMPORTHTML`.

#### Sample formula:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr | //td/a/@title"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8")}
```

- The URL of `https://www.tradeskillmaster.com/black-market?realm=EU-draenor` is put in the cell "A1".
- Column "A" is retrieved from `QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr | //td/a/@title")`. In this case, the xpath of `//tr` and `//td/a/@title` have the value and title of the column "A", respectively.
- Column "B" to "H" are retrieved from `QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8")`. In this case, the 1st column is removed.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

if the table contains JavaScript elements (which it does in your case) then such elements are not possible to import into Google Sheet with any formula. scraping of JS in GS is just not supported.